# TypeScript getting wrong this scope

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am aware of `this` scopes but I am new to TypeScript and classes in JavaScript. I am trying to access class properties within a function which is bound to a class property (to be more specific it's bound to a Socket object).

```
export class BrawlStarsClient {
  credentials:object
  dataBuffers:Array<Buffer>
  pingInterval:number

  constructor(credentials:object, options:object = null) {
    if (!credentials) throw new Error('No credentials have been passed to constructor')
    this.credentials = credentials

    // Setup socket
    this.client = new Socket()
    this.client.on('connect', this.onConnect)
  }

  onConnect():void {
    // In this function this refers to the socket object which is not desired
    this.dataBuffers = []
    this.pingInterval = null

    const initPacket = packetBuilder.buildLoginPacket(this.credentials)
    this.client.write(initPacket)
  }
}
```

In `onConnect()` this refers to the socket object instead of the class. What I've tried is rewriting the onConnect function to an arrow function, but that didn't help either:

`onConnect():void {` became   `onConnect = ():void => {`

**My question:**

How can I access my class properties inside of my onConnect() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.bind`. `.bind` will carry the arguments forward to the inner function.

```
this.client.on('connect', this.onConnect.bind(this));
```

or a arrow function. You will manually have to pass arguments here.

```
this.client.on('connect', () => this.onConnect());
```

Comment: What is the major difference between the two? Are there any advantages or disadvantages for one of them?

Answer (score 2):

Bind `this` in `constructor`:

```
this.onConnect = this.onConnect.bind(this);
```

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value[.]